# error while loading shared libraries: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql

использую Mysql.
Но при подключении программа требует именно  libmariadb.so.3

В интернете нашел что можно сделать симлинк такой командой:

`ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadb.so.3`

Ubuntu 20.04
Но ошибка все равно вылазит. Подскажите в чем дело
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Помогло

`apt install libmariadb3`

И линковок не надо